# Choosing rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame`, `df`:

```
Property   Area   dist
A           50     2
B           100    3
C           20     10
D            1     15
E           20     16
F            3     25
```

I want the final dataframe to have the form:

```
Property   Area   dist
A           50     2
C           20     10
F            3     25
```

i.e: I want to omit rows which are closer than 8 to each.

Comment: have u tired anything?

Comment: What do you mean by `closer than 8 to each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code meets your problem statement.  Basic idea is to gather the set of `dist` values to keep, and then apply those values to the dataframe.

**Code:**

```
# find the dist values to keep
to_keep = set()
min_value = None
min_dist = 8
for dist in sorted(df['dist']):
    if min_value <= dist - min_dist:
        min_value = dist
        to_keep.add(dist)

# build a new data frame with just the keep values
new_df = df.query('dist in @to_keep')
print(new_df)
```

**Produces:**

```
   Area  dist
A    50     2
C    20    10
F     3    25
```

**Sample data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
props = np.array([
    ('Property', 'Area', 'dist'),
    ('A',           50,      2),
    ('B',          100,      3),
    ('C',           20,     10),
    ('D',            1,     15),
    ('E',           20,     16),
    ('F',            3,     25),
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=props[1:, 1:],
                  index=props[1:, 0],
                  columns=props[0, 1:]).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works till the step new_df = df.query('dist in @to_keep'), where I get the error : raise ImportError("'numexpr' not found. Cannot use "
ImportError: 'numexpr' not found. Cannot use engine='numexpr' for query/eval if 'numexpr' is not installed

Comment: I installed numexpr and everything worked fine, thanks